# PostgresQL work and home addresses

Tags: postgresql

I'm designing my first Postgres database. The database will have restaurants and their owners and workers. This is a historical database for Croatian restaurants in LA at the turn of the last century.

My problem is whether to create two address tables—one for restaurants and one for residences of the people (both owners and workers, and they may be both over time). Rarely, but it happens, the owner lived at the restaurant.

I'm inclined to create two tables. Maybe this will be obvious after I start actually building the database (I have, but then stepped back and read more about db design). Note that eventually this will become a PostGIS db, but I'm starting with PostgresQL as a stepping stone.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an "Address" (or "location") table. Have both "restaurant" and "owner" refer to it.